# structure of the windows OS

Tags: windows, operating-system

I have some knowledge on OS (really little.)
I would like to know a lot about specifically the Windows OS (e.g. win 7)

I know, it's the most dominant OS out there, and there is an enormous amount of work I`ll have to do.
Where do I start? what are beginner/intermediate books/articles/websites that I should read?

The first thing I wonder about is that the compiler turns my C programs to binary code, however when I open the (exe) result files, I find something other than 0 and 1.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get very far studying a commercial, closed-source OS.

Comment: I just would like to know how much ever I can learn...

Comment: "The first thing I wonder about is that the compiler turns my C programs to binary code, however when I open the (exe) result files, I find something other than 0 and 1." If you are to understand the inner workings of operating systems, you have to know some basics on how computers work. For instance, you should know (in principle) what happens if you open an executable 1) in an ASCII text editor and 2) in a hex editor. If you do not know this, you aren't going to understand how an OS work. Sorry. Learn the basics first.

Comment: I didn't claim I know basics of OSes.. I only know something about OSes.. there is something called multiprogramming... there is something called times sharing...there is something called RTOS... that`s what I know

Comment: The statement that Windows is "Closed" in the literal meaning is inaccurate - http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/default.mspx

Comment: There is also something called *books*

Answer (score 3):

I can't point you in a direction as far as books go, but I can clarify this:

> The first thing I wonder about is that the compiler turns my C programs to binary code, however when I open the (exe) result files, I find something other than 0 and 1.

Your programs are in fact compiled to binary.  *Everything* on your computer is stored in binary.

The reason you do not see ones and zeroes is because of the makeup of character encodings.  It takes eight bits, which can have the value 0 or 1, to store one byte.  A lot of programs and character encodings represent one byte as one character (with the caveat of non-ASCII unicode characters, but that's not terribly important in this discussion).

So what's going on is that the program you are using to open the file is interpreting sequences of eight bits and turning those eight bits into one character.  So each character you see when you open the file is, in fact, eight ones and zeros.  The most basic mapping between bytes and characters is [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).  The character "A", for example, is represented in binary as 01000001.  so when the program you use to open the file sees that bit sequence, it will display "A" in its place.

Answer (score 3):

A nice book to read if you are interested in the Microsoft Windows operating system is [*The Old New Thing*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) by Microsoft legend Raymond Chen. It is very easy reading if you are a Win32 programmer, and even if you are not (even if you are not a programmer at all!) many of the chapters are still readily accessible.

Otherwise, to understand the Microsoft Windows OS, you need to understand the Windows API. You learn this by writing programs for the Windows (native) platform, and the official documentation, which is very good, is [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663300(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are a series of books titled "Windows Internals" that could probably keep you busy for the better part of a couple years. Also, Microsoft has been known to release source code to universities to study...

Answer (score 0):

well, if you study the win32 api you will learn a lot about high-level os
(petzold is the king, and it's not about win7 just win32....)

If you want to study about low level, study the processor assembler language.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of resources out there for learning operating systems in general, many of which don't really focus on Windows because, as John pointed out, it's very closed and not very useful academically.  You may want to look into something like [Minix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX), which is very useful academically.  It's small, light, and made pretty much for the sole purpose of education.

From there you can branch out into other OSes (even Windows, as far as not being able to look under the hood can take you) armed with a greater knowledge of what an OS is and does, as well as more knowledge of the inner workings of the computer itself.  (For example, opening executable code in I assume a text editor, such as Notepad, to try to see the 1s and 0s, which as cdhowie pointed out eloquently is not doing what you think it's doing.)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally look into the ReactOS project - a working windows clone.
The code con give some ideas of how windows is implemented...

Here is  the site:
www. reactos. org

Comment: I have tried this OS in a virtual machine. And I have never seen a buggier piece of software in my life. (But it might be due to the virtualization, who knows.)